# Visual Studio Installer gets stuck on verify/download loop

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-installer

When I launch the Visual Studio Installer, it will download the installation files, then attempt to verify them, then redownload them, and ultimately fail in verifying them again.[image: Visual Studio Installer getting stuck on verifying]

The logs show that the bootstrapper fails to run, and exits with an unknown error.
I am on windows 21H2, and I have checked previous errors on stack overflow but most of them are about the installer not starting.

Below are the installer and bootstrap logs:

```
[3/5/2024, 14:30:38] === Logging started: 2024/03/05 14:30:38 ===
[3/5/2024, 14:30:38] Executable: C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\VisualStudioSetup.exe v17.9.34622.214
[3/5/2024, 14:30:38] --- logging level: standard ---
[3/5/2024, 14:30:38] Directory 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\9b9e633ceab94a60cf6c07d2\' has been selected for file extraction
[3/5/2024, 14:30:38] Extracting files to: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\9b9e633ceab94a60cf6c07d2\
[3/5/2024, 14:30:38] Extraction took 593 milliseconds
[3/5/2024, 14:30:38] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\VisualStudioSetup.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\<username>\Downloads"'
[3/5/2024, 14:32:50] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[3/5/2024, 14:32:50] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x138b
[3/5/2024, 14:32:50] === Logging stopped: 2024/03/05 14:32:50 ===
```

```
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Assembly version: 3.9.2164.57262.
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Creating new ExperimentationService
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Telemetry property VS.ABExp.Flights : 
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Commandline arguments = --env,_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\Tenai\Downloads\VisualStudioSetup.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\Tenai\Downloads
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] C2R signature arguments = {sku, community, channel, Release, cid, 2030:2af3680f0a6b4dce8f8afe3eb4906032}
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Parent process name = VisualStudioSetup
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Parent process product version = 17.9.34622.214
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] CampaignId = 2030:2af3680f0a6b4dce8f8afe3eb4906032
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Warning: ResponseId not available in 'vs_setup_bootstrapper.config'. Trying to parse filename.
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:39] Warning: loading config settings: -update --update --layout -offline --offline --locale --layout --originalworkingdir --installLayoutPath --env
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] DownloadURL = https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/installer
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] InstallLocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] OfflineFilePath = 
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] LayoutLocation = 
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] ExecutableArguments = /finalizeInstall install --in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_202403051430399701.json" --locale en-US --activityId "8554f084-0e25-4d2d-b4c6-ac1e28fa28e4" --campaign "2030:2af3680f0a6b4dce8f8afe3eb4906032"
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] OSVersion = Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19044.0
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] Starting to detect the existing VS and .NET...
[28ec:0001][2024-03-05T14:30:40] Finished detecting the existing VS and .Net
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Authentication Environment variable setting value: null
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Authenticate: True
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Download requested: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/09cec1a8-8fec-4a0b-af5e-bb82c3f2771b/7bb6ed7ff37728c361fa3ff4799aeb5c/latestinstaller.json
[28ec:0016][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/09cec1a8-8fec-4a0b-af5e-bb82c3f2771b/7bb6ed7ff37728c361fa3ff4799aeb5c/latestinstaller.json' using engine 'WebClient'
[28ec:0016][2024-03-05T14:30:41] ManifestVerifier Result: Success
[28ec:0016][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/09cec1a8-8fec-4a0b-af5e-bb82c3f2771b/7bb6ed7ff37728c361fa3ff4799aeb5c/latestinstaller.json' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:30:41] ManifestVerifier Result: Success
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Existing client is unsupported: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\setup.exe does not exist.
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Beginning file download. File = https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/installer.
[28ec:0017][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Download requested: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:41] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'WebClient'
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:45] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:45] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:45] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:45] Download failed using WebClient engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:45] Sleeping 5000 milliseconds before retrying download.
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:50] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'Bits'
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:54] Completing job 'VsBitsDownloadJob - 1153316611'.
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:54] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:54] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:54] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:54] Download failed using Bits engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:30:54] Sleeping 10000 milliseconds before retrying download.
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:31:04] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'WinInet'
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:31:04] Querying HTTP information failed with error code: 12150
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:31:08] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:31:08] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:31:08] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:0018][2024-03-05T14:31:08] Download failed using WinInet engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:31:08] Error 0x80096004: Failed to download. Error : Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:31:13] Beginning file download. File = https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/installer.
[28ec:0011][2024-03-05T14:31:13] Download requested: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:13] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'WebClient'
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:17] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:17] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:17] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:17] Download failed using WebClient engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:17] Sleeping 5000 milliseconds before retrying download.
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:22] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'Bits'
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:26] Completing job 'VsBitsDownloadJob - 1153316611'.
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:26] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:26] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:26] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:26] Download failed using Bits engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:26] Sleeping 10000 milliseconds before retrying download.
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:36] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'WinInet'
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:36] Querying HTTP information failed with error code: 12150
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:40] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:40] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:40] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:0015][2024-03-05T14:31:40] Download failed using WinInet engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:31:40] Error 0x80096004: Failed to download. Error : Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:31:45] Beginning file download. File = https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/installer.
[28ec:001a][2024-03-05T14:31:45] Download requested: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:45] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'WebClient'
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:48] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:48] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:48] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:48] Download failed using WebClient engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:48] Sleeping 5000 milliseconds before retrying download.
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:53] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'Bits'
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:57] Completing job 'VsBitsDownloadJob - 1153316611'.
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:57] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:57] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:57] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:57] Download failed using Bits engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:31:57] Sleeping 10000 milliseconds before retrying download.
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:32:07] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5e7b923b-7d89-4e14-95b8-a84ab168e243/2D90210D650FA6E88C825004A112C3E5304FD92EBCE4088DFC43576B277D6F29/vs_installer.opc' using engine 'WinInet'
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:32:07] Querying HTTP information failed with error code: 12150
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Error 0x80096004: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"

[28ec:001b][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Download failed using WinInet engine. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Security.InvalidSignatureException: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Error 0x80096004: Failed to download. Error : Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.DownloadManager.DownloadWithRetry(IDownloadEngine[] engines, Uri uri, Stream outputStream, ProgressUpdateCallback progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DownloadContext downloadContext, Boolean verifySignature)
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: Sending Watson Bucket with:
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P1  = vs_setup_bootstrapper
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P2  = 3.9.2164.57262
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P3  = 
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P4  = Install
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P5  = https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/installer
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P6  = n/a
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P7  = 0x80096004
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P8  = 
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P9  = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: P10 = VisualStudio.17.Release
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Watson: Including Log : C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_bootstrapper_20240305143039.log
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\mqhnxw2.jl0\vs_installer.opc failed to download https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/installer. Failure: Package signature verification threw exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
, for path: vs_installer.opc"
[28ec:0010][2024-03-05T14:32:11] Bootstrapper failed with known error.
```

Comment: For some reason or another, the service `CNG Key Isolation` was disabled somehow. Re-enabling it fixed the installer.